# kurento-player took too long to start

Tags: java, webrtc, kurento

I am trying the kurento-player demo on the doc site for streaming RTSP video to the webrtcEndPoint.
I found it took about 7 to 10 seconds to show the video.
As far as I concerned, the latency should be related to :

1. the decoding and encoding time, since the RTSP stream is in h264.
2. the network latency between kurento-media-server and the RTSP streaming.(the network environment should have been pretty stable)
3. the latency generated from kurento-player since the client side started the sdpOffer, then the kurento-media-server start to decode the stream. (probably? In fact, the client seems completed the connection pretty quick, but I still need to wait more time before the video showed up)

Any suggestion for improvment?